# how Fix this two elements layout with css to be on same line?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have the following code in Angular html page which i need to make the label sit next to the dropdown list

```
<div *ngIf="this.userRole == 'myrequests' " class="col-2" [ngClass]="{ 'd-none': view != 'list' }" id="statusFilter">
      <label class="font-weight-bold text-secondary" for="statusFilter">Filter By Status:</label>
      <select style="display: inline-block ;"
        name="statusFilter"
        [(ngModel)]="statusFilter"
        class="form-control"
        (change)="setStatusFilter()">
        <option  [value]="'none'" disabled selected><strong> Choose Filter: </strong></option> 
        <option   *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status.name">
            {{ status.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

typescript file has the array:

```
  statuses = [
    { id: 0, name: "All" },
    { id: 1, name: "Approved" },
    { id: 2, name: "Created" },
    { id: 3, name: "Rejected" },
    { id: 4, name: "Cancelled" },
    { id: 5, name: "Approval Pending" },
  ];
```

The desired layout I want to be on the same line

the current situation as shown in this image:
[image]

Comment: make that div a flexbox

Comment: Don’t mention it, gave an upvote as well.

Answer (score -1):

For the parent class, use flexbox:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could give the label a display: inline-block; aswell.

Or you could put the label and  both in a different div and give those div's a certain width.